# combine values from all rows and columns into one column oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Can I combine all distinct values from multiple rows/columns returned from an sql query into one column. e.g.

```
org1 | org2 | org 3
-------------------
27   | 2710 | 27100
27   | 2710 | 27101
27   | 2711 | 27111
```

to

```
orgs
-----
27
2710
2711
27100
27101
27111
```

I would like to then join this with the user in order to create a user to org mapping table

Comment: what version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Could do it the lazy way

```
Select org1 as org1 FROm table

UNION ALL

SELECT org2 as org1 FROM table

UNION ALL 

SELECT org3 AS org1 From Table
```

Comment: Why is this the lazy way?  Is there a better way?

Comment: @Andrew, mostly intuition, I feel as if there is a better way to do it, but I have no clue to what it'd be.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT org1 AS orgs FROM t
UNION
SELECT org2 FROM t
UNION
SELECT org3 FROM t
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Unions:

```
select
org1
from...
union 
select 
org2 from
...
```